# How to call child component function with parameter in parent component in angular

Tags: angular

Can anybody suggest How to call child component function with parameter in parent component in angular

```
<app-child> <app-child> calling child component how to call this set method?

    in my child component have below set function 
    set id (id: number){
    
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about input/output? Also, it is working with the setter/getter as well.

If I understand right, you can use it like this

**your parent component**

```
export class ParentComponent {
   id: string;

   ngOnInit() {
       setTimeout(() => { this.id = 'SomeUniqueId'; }, 3000)
   }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core'; 

export class ChildComponent {
   private _id: string;
   @Input() set id(value: string) {
       this._id = value;
       // you can call what function you want;

       this.anotherFunction();

   }

   get id() { return this._id; }

  anotherFunction() { console.log('it works')}
}
```

**Parent Template**

```
<app-child [id]="id"> <app-child>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for your request I think you would need to have the param (`id`) into the parent component. Then, you'll have to use `@Viewchild` like this :

Child component :

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child-cmp',
  template: '<p>child</p>'
})
class ChildCmp {
  setId(id: number) {}
}
```

parent component :

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'some-cmp',
  template: '<child-cmp></child-cmp>',
  directives: [ChildCmp]
})
class SomeCmp implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(ChildCmp) child:ChildCmp;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const id = 5; // You must have the id here
    this.child.set(id);
  }
}
```

---

If, for some reason, the wanted id is into the child component :

Child component :

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child-cmp',
  template: '<p>child</p>'
})
class ChildCmp {
  id = 5;
  setId() {}
}
```

Parent component :

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.child.set(this.child.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

parent.component.html

```html
<app-child #childRef> <app-child>
```

parent.component.ts

```js
@ViewChild( "childRef", { static: false } ) childRef;


ngAfterViewInit() {
  childRef.CHILD_FUNCTION()
}

parentFunction() {
  childRef.CHILD_FUNCTION()
}
```